# Как правильнее дать большое количество CSS классов в обработку для jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, json

Допустип есть некая страница с большим набором элементов (Bootstrap).
Например необходимо забиндить на определенный набор CSS классов, определенные события или добавить к DOM элементам какие то элементы (ну скажем кнопку удаления со страницы).

Набор классов может быть размером 100-200 и более штук. Он так же может меняться динамически, например добавился какой то класс, и надо чтобы скрипт и его обработал после обновления страницы.

Какой способ передачи этого самого набора классов выбрать в данном случае, так чтобы это работало быстро при инициализации скрипта?

> Собственно вопрос возникает в связи с тем что хардкордить эти самые классы в скрипт явно нельзя, ибо получится каша да и динамики не будет никакой в таком случае.
>
> По большому счету, задача сводится к тому, чтобы всем элементам на
>   странице, у которых прописан тот или иной класс, появились доп
>   элементы, например кнопка. При нажатии на кнопку, будет вызываться функция, в которую должны прийти параметрами, DOM объект на котором нажали кнопку. Количество и названия классов могут меняться. (например Bootstrap 2.x, Bootstrap 3.x или что то произвольное)

Comment: Позвольте спросить, а зачем вам биндить событие на 100-200 (!) классов?! Не легче ли к нужным элементам кинуть один левый класс, на котором и будет висеть событие? И как эти классы добавляются? Через ajax, посредством функции, наподобие `addClass`?

Comment: Новые классы не добавляются на страницу, новые классы добавляются в базу данных, и потом каким то образом должны попадать на обработку в скрипт, который биндит событие или добавляет элементы к ним.

Comment: Если у нас есть уже 200 классов, то добавление еще одного класса на который будет биндиться событие, не однозначно верное решение имхо. Вопрос все же каким образом обработать элементы на странице , у которых прописаны те классы, из этого списка.

Comment: Я исправил свой ответ, добавив в него массив. Теперь он полностью соответсвует вашим требованиям (если я ничего не упустил). Так что смотрите, пробуйте.

Comment: Первый вопрос, вам это точно нужно в бд и на беке? Зачем? Что мешает хардкодить это в отдельной jsке-jsonе?

Comment: В общем вас никто не заставляет хардкодить этот список классов в отдельный бандл, можно подлючить js файл типа config.js в котором он зашит. Я думаю в базе этому списку классов не место, потому что это чисто фронтовая сущность и никаких агрегатов по нему в жизни не понадобится. На бэке тоже, если у вас конечно не изоморфное приложение (сомневаюсь, вас наверное занимали бы другие вопросы). Возможно разумно запретить ему кешироваться на браузерном уровне.

Comment: Разумно все это знать в базе и на беке только если у вас какая-та админка задумывается через которую этот список будет редактироваться.

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму Да это какраз тот случай, когда этот список будет редактироваться и пополнятся, в исходной задаче это указано и это не банальный сайт для юзеров а приложение для узкого круга лиц.

Answer (score 4):

С трудом, но понял вашу проблему. Если уж так хочется поиграться, то из бд через AJAX выгружайте обычный массив со списком классов, потом записываете этот список классов с помощью цикла, в строку по такому алгоритму (в принципе, это можно сделать и на стороне бэкенда):

```
var per = '.class_1, .class_2 [, ...]';
```

Далее отрабатываете событие по переменной `per`. К примеру, у меня получился такой код, для события `click()`:

```js
$(function() {
  var arr = ['cl1', 'cl4'];
  var per = arr.map(elem => '.' + elem).join(',');

  $(per).click(function() {
    $(this).css({
      'border': '1px solid white'
    });
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

div,
p,
span,
a {
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
  float: left;
  border: 3px solid yellow;
}

div {
  background: black;
}

p {
  background: red;
}

span {
  background: blue;
}

a {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cl1"></div>
<p class="cl2"></p>
<span class="cl3"></span>
<a class="cl4"></a>
```

В примере я сделал 4 объекта. Событие повесил на классы `cl1` и `cl4`. Вручную задал массив, чтобы сделать его перебор. Вы же этот массив будете получать из БД. В принципе, всё работает. Насколько это адекватно - я вам не подскажу, так как есть гуру, которые лучше меня разбираются. Работает? - Да, конечно (иначе бы я не писал)! :)